# Routing traffic from LAN over VPN link out to 'net; works from router, not from LAN. What route is missing?

Tags: vpn, firewall, routing, openvpn, policy-routing

I have 3 machines.  2, routers, are connected over a VPN.  The 3rd is a PC on the lan behind one of the routers.

```
          internet
              |
              |
ROUTER S1  external: YYY.56.52.56 (eth0)
             vpn:      10.0.0.1 (tun0)
              |
              |
ROUTER S2    vpn:      10.0.0.2 (tun0)
           external: XXX.19.10.126 (eth0) -------------------internet
           internal: 192.168.3.10, 10.19.26.10 (eth1)
     |
     |
LAN PC1     external: 192.168.3.16, 10.19.26.7 (eth0)
```

I want to move selected traffic from the LAN, over the VPN, out to the 'NET.

My routing policy on ROUTER S2 directs iptables-marked traffic from 10.19.26.0/24 so that it traverses the VPN.

From the router, ROUTER S2

```
ping -I 10.19.26.10 72.14.191.202
```

works - the ping request is correctly routed over the VPN, to the target, and the ping reply is received.

But from the lan behind it, LAN PC1

```
ping -I 10.19.26.7 72.14.191.202
```

doesn't.  No response.

What specific route, on what machine, am I missing?

Comment: Is Router S1 the internet Router for the YYY.56.52.56 network?

Comment: Maybe you need Proxy Arp on Router S1

Comment: Looking at it from LANPC1, it will send unknown traffic out via its gateway ip. What is it set to?

Comment: LANPC1 does not know about routers, so it doesn't matter how the router is setup. All it needs to know is to send this packet of an unknown network to a gateway ip address. Do you have a gateway address on LANPC1?